# Refreshing a table with Visual Studio 2010, Entity Framework 5.0, .Net Framework 4.0 forces you to delete the table and re-add it

Tags: entity

I wanted to make a change to a table in the edmx designer since I added a column in our Sql Server DB (Update Model fromm Database). When the wizard came up to refresh a table, the table that was to be refreshed WAS NOT IN THE LIST (in the Refresh tab), even though it was sitting on the designer.

I had to delete the table, go thru the wizard again to see the table underneath the "Add" tab and was able to re-add it with the new column.

The problem with this approach is it's fine if you have one or two tables, but what if you have many tables in your model? You'd have to delete the entire model and re-select each table again to re-create your model.

Am I missing a step here or what?

As far as I can tell, the same thing happens using Visual Studio 2012 with the 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to apply SP 1 to both VS 2010 & 2012 in order to get it to work.